# Solving numerically the 1D Kuramoto-Sivashinsky Equation using spectral methods

Tags: python, numerics, differential-equations, fourier-analysis, spectral-method

Lately, I've been trying to solve numerically the **1D Kuramoto-Sivashinsky Equation** using spectral methods.

Let $\nu$ be the viscosity and $[0,L]$ the domain. The 1D equation is,
$$
u_t + uu_x + u_{xx} + \nu u_{xxxx} = 0 \iff u_t = -  uu_x - (u_{xx} + \nu u_{xxxx})
$$

Introducing the linear operator
$$
\mathcal{L}u = - (u_{xx} + \nu u_{xxxx})
$$
and the non-linear operator
$$
\mathcal{N}u = - u u_x = - \frac{1}{2} u^2_{x}
$$
We can write this PDE as a sum of these two operators
$$
u_t =  \mathcal{L}u + \mathcal{N}u
$$

We can solve the linear part with a **Crank-Nicholson** scheme
\begin{equation}
    \frac{u(x,t + \Delta t) - u(x,t)}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathcal{L}u(x,t + \Delta t) + \mathcal{L}u(x,t) \right)
\end{equation}

And we can solve the non-linear part with an **Adam Bashforth** scheme
\begin{equation}
    \frac{u(x,t + \Delta t) - u(x,t)}{\Delta t} = \frac{3}{2} \mathcal{N}u(x,t) - \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N} u(x,t - \Delta t)
\end{equation}

After some algebra and going into Fourier space, we find
\begin{equation}
    \hat{u}(k, t + \Delta t) = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\Delta t}{2} \mathcal{F}[\mathcal{L}]} \left( \left[1 + \frac{\Delta t}{2} \mathcal{F}[\mathcal{L}] \right] \hat{u}(k,t) + \left[ \frac{3}{2} \mathcal{F}[\mathcal{N}] (\hat{u}(k,t))^2 - \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{F} [\mathcal{N}] (\hat{u}(k,t - \Delta t))^2 \right] \Delta t \right)
\end{equation}

where the Fourier transform of the linear and non-linear operator is given by
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{F}[\mathcal{L}] &= - \left(i \frac{2\pi}{L} k \right)^2 - \nu \left(i \frac{2\pi}{L} k \right)^4 = \left( \frac{2\pi}{L} k \right)^2 - \nu \left( \frac{2\pi}{L} k \right)^4 \\
    \mathcal{F}[\mathcal{N}u(x,t)] &= - \frac{1}{2} \left(i \frac{2\pi}{L} k \right) \hat{u}^2(k,t)
\end{align*}

I'm trying to "show" that for $L = 100$ we have chaos. Taking $\nu = 1$, $x \in [0, L]$ where $L = 100$, $t \in [0, 200]$ and the initial condition,
\begin{equation}
    u(x,0) = \cos(2\pi x / L) + 0.1 \cos(4\pi x / L)
\end{equation}

We're also discretizing the domain in $N = 1024$ points and taking a step time $\Delta t = 0.05$.

The 1D plot I'm trying to obtain is the following,

[image: chaos goal]

However, the one I obtain is different. I guess I'm not too far away of obtaining the good one but the chaos is not very much visible in mine.

[image: choas fail]

And here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

nu = 1
L = 100 
nx = 1024

t0 = 0 
tN = 200
dt = 0.05
nt = int((tN - t0) / 0.05)

# wave number mesh
k = np.arange(-nx/2, nx/2, 1)

t = np.linspace(start=t0, stop=tN, num=nt)
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=L, num=nx)

# solution mesh in real space
u = np.ones((nx, nt))
# solution mesh in Fourier space
u_hat = np.ones((nx, nt), dtype=complex)

# initial condition 
u0 = np.cos((2 * np.pi * x) / L) + 0.1 * np.cos((4 * np.pi * x) / L)

# Fourier transform of initial condition
u0_hat = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u0))

# set initial condition in real and Fourier mesh
u[:,0] = u0
u_hat[:,0] = u0_hat

# Fourier Transform of the linear operator
FL = (((2 * np.pi) / L) * k) ** 2 - nu * (((2 * np.pi) / L) * k) ** 4
# Fourier Transform of the non-linear operator
FN = - (1 / 2) * ((1j) * ((2 * np.pi) / L) * k)

# resolve EDP in Fourier space
for j in range(0,nt-1):
  uhat_current = u_hat[:,j]
  if j == 0:
    uhat_last = u_hat[:,0]
  else:
    uhat_last = u_hat[:,j-1]
  
  # compute solution in Fourier space through a finite difference method
  # Cranck-Nicholson + Adam 
  u_hat[:,j+1] = (1 / (1 - (dt / 2) * FL)) * ( (1 + (dt / 2) * FL) * uhat_current + ( ((3 / 2) * FN) * (uhat_current ** 2) - ((1 / 2) * FN) * (uhat_last ** 2) ) * dt )
  # go back in real space
  u[:,j+1] = np.real(nx * np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(u_hat[:,j+1])))

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

xx, tt = np.meshgrid(x, t)
levels = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
cs = ax.contourf(xx, tt, u.T, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(cs)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("t")
ax.set_title(f"Kuramoto-Sivashinsky: L = {L}, nu = {nu}")
```

After checking multiple times computations and code, I don't see where I'm wrong ? Maybe there's some non-linear effect I should manage ?

Comment: Something suspicious about applying Fourier transform to nonlinear operator, that should lead to a convolution.

Comment: Indeed. I applied a pseudo-spectral method to deal with non-linearities. No I have the good plot. Gonna edit my post with this solution.

Comment: Do you just need a KSE solver or are you writing your own one for the learning experience? Because https://github.com/jswhit/pyks is another pseudospectral solver I've used in research.

Comment: Well I believe @MaximUmansky is right here and the Fourier transform of your nonlinear term is indeed wrong. I think you need to know that: $$\mathcal{F} [ (f(x))^{2} ] \neq (\mathcal{F} [ f(x) ])^{2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Indeed the problem was that you were trying to calculate your nonlinear term incorrectly and you forgot that:

$$\mathcal{F}[(f(x))^{2}] \neq (\mathcal{F}[f(x)])^{2}$$

I changed your code to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

nu = 1
L = 100 
nx = 1024

t0 = 0 
tN = 200
dt = 0.05
nt = int((tN - t0) / 0.05)

# wave number mesh
k = np.arange(-nx/2, nx/2, 1)

t = np.linspace(start=t0, stop=tN, num=nt)
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=L, num=nx)

# solution mesh in real space
u = np.ones((nx, nt))
# solution mesh in Fourier space
u_hat = np.ones((nx, nt), dtype=complex)

u_hat2 = np.ones((nx, nt), dtype=complex)

# initial condition 
u0 = np.cos((2 * np.pi * x) / L) + 0.1 * np.cos((4 * np.pi * x) / L)

# Fourier transform of initial condition
u0_hat = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u0))

u0_hat2 = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u0**2))

# set initial condition in real and Fourier mesh
u[:,0] = u0
u_hat[:,0] = u0_hat

u_hat2[:,0] = u0_hat2

# Fourier Transform of the linear operator
FL = (((2 * np.pi) / L) * k) ** 2 - nu * (((2 * np.pi) / L) * k) ** 4
# Fourier Transform of the non-linear operator
FN = - (1 / 2) * ((1j) * ((2 * np.pi) / L) * k)

# resolve EDP in Fourier space
for j in range(0,nt-1):
  uhat_current = u_hat[:,j]
  uhat_current2 = u_hat2[:,j]
  if j == 0:
    uhat_last = u_hat[:,0]
    uhat_last2 = u_hat2[:,0]
  else:
    uhat_last = u_hat[:,j-1]
    uhat_last2 = u_hat2[:,j-1]
  
  # compute solution in Fourier space through a finite difference method
  # Cranck-Nicholson + Adam 
  u_hat[:,j+1] = (1 / (1 - (dt / 2) * FL)) * ( (1 + (dt / 2) * FL) * uhat_current + ( ((3 / 2) * FN) * (uhat_current2) - ((1 / 2) * FN) * (uhat_last2) ) * dt )
  # go back in real space
  u[:,j+1] = np.real(nx * np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(u_hat[:,j+1])))
  u_hat2[:,j+1] = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u[:,j+1]**2))

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

xx, tt = np.meshgrid(x, t)
levels = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
cs = ax.contourf(xx, tt, u.T, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(cs)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("t")
ax.set_title(f"Kuramoto-Sivashinsky: L = {L}, nu = {nu}")
```

And I got similar answer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code but when I try the code with T = 1000, it is not stable. When I add

```
u_hat[:,j+1] = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u[:,j+1]))
```

which removes the accumulated error in the imaginary part, I can get stable results for T=1000

The code becomes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

nu = 1
L = 100 
nx = 1024

t0 = 0 
tN = 1000
dt = 0.05
nt = int((tN - t0) / 0.05)

# wave number mesh
k = np.arange(-nx/2, nx/2, 1)

t = np.linspace(start=t0, stop=tN, num=nt)
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=L, num=nx)

# solution mesh in real space
u = np.ones((nx, nt))
# solution mesh in Fourier space
u_hat = np.ones((nx, nt), dtype=complex)

u_hat2 = np.ones((nx, nt), dtype=complex)

# initial condition 
u0 = np.cos((2 * np.pi * x) / L) + 0.1 * np.cos((4 * np.pi * x) / L)

# Fourier transform of initial condition
u0_hat = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u0))

u0_hat2 = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u0**2))

# set initial condition in real and Fourier mesh
u[:,0] = u0
u_hat[:,0] = u0_hat

u_hat2[:,0] = u0_hat2

# Fourier Transform of the linear operator
FL = (((2 * np.pi) / L) * k) ** 2 - nu * (((2 * np.pi) / L) * k) ** 4
# Fourier Transform of the non-linear operator
FN = - (1 / 2) * ((1j) * ((2 * np.pi) / L) * k)

# resolve EDP in Fourier space
for j in range(0,nt-1):
  uhat_current = u_hat[:,j]
  uhat_current2 = u_hat2[:,j]
  if j == 0:
    uhat_last = u_hat[:,0]
    uhat_last2 = u_hat2[:,0]
  else:
    uhat_last = u_hat[:,j-1]
    uhat_last2 = u_hat2[:,j-1]
  
  # compute solution in Fourier space through a finite difference method
  # Cranck-Nicholson + Adam 
  u_hat[:,j+1] = (1 / (1 - (dt / 2) * FL)) * ( (1 + (dt / 2) * FL) * uhat_current + ( ((3 / 2) * FN) * (uhat_current2) - ((1 / 2) * FN) * (uhat_last2) ) * dt )
  # go back in real space
  u[:,j+1] = np.real(nx * np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(u_hat[:,j+1])))

  # clean the imaginary part contribution in u_hat
  u_hat[:,j+1] = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u[:,j+1]))

  u_hat2[:,j+1] = (1 / nx) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(u[:,j+1]**2))

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

xx, tt = np.meshgrid(x, t)
levels = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
cs = ax.contourf(xx, tt, u.T, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(cs)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("t")
ax.set_title(f"Kuramoto-Sivashinsky: L = {L}, nu = {nu}")
```

[image]

Comment: It's not the answer to the question. It wasn't meant to be stable for any $t$ and OP didn't want to run it for $t > 200$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).